# Why is $\ell$ in $\mathbf F = I~\ell \times \mathbf B$ taken as shortest distance?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-current

The equation [$\mathbf F = I~\ell \times \mathbf B$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Force_on_a_current-carrying_wire) works good for a straight wire. But in cases where the wire is bent in the form of a sine curve or in a circle and the magnetic field is assumed perpendicular to the plane of the wire, $\ell$ is taken as the shortest distance between the points from where the current enters the magnetic field and exits. Why not the whole length??
For eg- a problem in the book I am referring takes $\ell$ as the diameter of a semicircular wire instead of the length of the wire to calculate the force on the wire.

Comment: Could it be that there is a "implicit dot product" - to get the force perpendicular to the wire, you need the dot product. In certain situations, this is equivalent to taking the "shortcut" - but it may not be generally true. You might want to expand your question with a diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The force per unit volume exerted by a magnetic field on a charged material is (see e.g. [Feynman](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_13.html#Ch13-S3)):$$\frac{\Delta \mathbf F}{\Delta V} = \mathbf j \times \mathbf B$$

In particular, for a thin wire, this reduces to: $$\mathbf f \equiv \frac {\Delta \mathbf F} {\Delta \ell}= \mathbf I \times \mathbf B,$$
where $\mathbf I = I\hat {\mathbf t}$ is tangent to the wire. To obtain the total resultant force on the wire, integrate $\mathbf f$ over the lenght of the wire: $$\mathbf F _{\text {res}}=\intop _\ell \mathbf f \text ds = \intop _\ell  I \hat {\mathbf t} \times \mathbf B \text d s.$$
If I and $\mathbf B$ are **constant** along the wire, they can be brought outside of the integral sign, giving the desired result ($\int \hat {\mathbf t} \text ds$ is by definition the displacement beetween the two ends of the wire).